# how to display the mark sheet on the next page using ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

i want to creat a web page that uses radiobuttons in a multiple choice quetions, but i want to do is to use a submit button to return the results to the next page with the mark sheet, so can you please help me with that. how to display the mark sheet on the next page using ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

Use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) state.

For example,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["key"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("marksheet.aspx");
    }
```

Code in Page_Load of marksheet.aspx,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["key"] != null)
        {
            object val = Session["key"];
            ...
        }
    }
```